# What's the reason for different output than expected for C++ program?

Tags: c++

I came across a program, which gives a different output than I expect. What could be the reason?

Program:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

//Class A
class A
{
    int x,y;
    public:
    //constructor
    A(int X,int Y):x(X),y(Y)
    {
    }
    A SetX(int X)
    {
        x = X;
        return *this;
    }
    A SetY(int Y)
    {
        y=Y;
        return *this;
    }
    void print()
    {
        cout << x << " " << y;
    }
};
int main()
{
    A a(5, 5);
    a.SetX(10).SetY(20);//???
    a.print();

}
```

As can be seen here, a is created with value 5,5. then SetX() and SetY() are called with values 10 & 20 respectively. Here I would expect the print(), to show output as 10, 20. But surprisingly the output is 10,5. What's happening is background? Any help is appreciated?

Comment: You want to return references in your setter functions: `A& SetY(int Y)`

Comment: That can be done for correct output. But do you know what's the reason for different output here?

Comment: _"But do you know what's the reason for different output here?"_ Because the second setter call will apply to a different (temporary) instance of `A` and not the original one.

Comment: Why and how a temporary object is created here? What are the conditions for that? Does it depend on the compiler or are there are predefined rules/conditions where a temporary object will be create?

Comment: If you don't use a reference a copy is made, that simple. That doesn't depend on the compiler.

Comment: Realize that C++ is different than Java and C# et. al. in that you can have objects and references to objects, and you need to understand the difference (pointers too).  Do you know the difference between the instance of an object, a reference to an instance of an object, and a pointer to an instance of an object, and for completeness, a pointer to a reference of an instance of an object?  Please tell us if you understand these C++ concepts, which do not all exist in those other languages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `A SetX(int X)` is returning a copy of the object, so when you do `a.SetX(10).SetY(20);` , the `.SetY` is operating on that copy - which then gets destroyed.

You want to change the function signature to `A& SetX(int X);` so that you return a reference to the original object rather than a copy.

Comment: Does it mean here default copy constructor is called while returing *this?

Comment: @santoshkumar - *conceptually* yes. But research `copy elision` as well.

Comment: Then what are the other ways by which the new object will be created? If _copy elision_ is applied here, then only **parameterized constructor** is the only option to create the temporary object. Is that right?

Comment: No. It's a lot more complicated than that.